# TypeError: Implicit conversion to a NumPy array is not allowed. Please use `.get()` to construct a NumPy array explicitly. - CuPy

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror, cupy

I would like to use the numpy function `np.float32(im)` with CuPy library in my code.

```
im = cupy.float32(im)
```

but when I run the code I'm facing this error:

```
TypeError: Implicit conversion to a NumPy array is not allowed. Please use `.get()` to construct a NumPy array explicitly.
```

Any fixes for that?

Answer (score 6):

You need to add `.get()` to `im` inside the brackets:

```
im = cupy.float32(im.get())
```